# Could it be considered fair-use to post a censored version of another YouTube video on YouTube?

Tags: copyright, fair-use

Regardless of if it is legal to download the video from YouTube in the first place, could it be considered fair-use to upload the video with some parts of the video and audio censored (giving credit to the original author)?

The specifics: I edited Taylor Swift's Shake it Off (titled "Taylor Swift - Shake it Off (censored)") to remove all the twerking as well as the entire bridge in order to make it kid-friendly (as I have kids who love the song and Taylor Swift). I put it on YouTube as a private video and got a ContentID match and after a couple of days didn't receive a Copyright Infringement Notice ... so I went ahead and made it public ... and of course it gets taken down a few days later.

I don't think I'll "fight" it; I'm just curious if there is any case-law out there similar to this situation.

Comment: I'm not going to speak to the legality of this. However, I will say people have been editing the smut produced by Hollywood since the start. Today there are services like [ClearPlay](https://www.clearplay.com/), [VidAngel](https://www.vidangel.com/), and [enJoy Movies Your Way](http://www.enjoymoviesyourway.com/) to block out offensive content and they seem to be operating within the law. I'm not familiar with similar services for music, but I would guess the same approach could easily be taken.

Comment: These services are often unlawful exploiting copyrights without a license.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No, you misunderstand Fair use and infringed copyright

Fair use only exists if enough of the [four factor](https://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/fair-use/four-factors/)s are given for it:

- The Transformative Factor
- The Nature of the Copyrighted Work
- The Amount and Substantiality of the Portion Taken
- The Effect of the Use Upon the Potential Market

You fail on all of them:

- Cutting the video does not alter the meaning or expression. which means it is nontransformative and thus against OP.
- Music is usually with fictional works, the best you can get here is "neutral*. but I would weigh against OP.
- Your Video took the total of the video and nothing else. Against OP.
- The full-length Video has a potential market that does include underage children. Your video tried to infringe on that market. Against OP.

## ERGO

You are not enacting Fair Use but infringe copyright.

## Similar case: Vidangel

Vidangel had been offering films in a censored fashion without the approval of the copyright holders. A court ruled that this is **not fair use** and it was [sanctioned for 65 Million US-dollar.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D5-qoJVQeNM)

Comment: Fair Use is determined based on the four considerations you list.  It doesn't necessarily require all elements to be satisfied. It's at least theoretically determined on a case-by-case basis, but I can't imagine this being Fair Use.

Comment: @DavidThornley corrected